# How to save user ID who edited the record - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to save the user ID who edited the article on my aplication. I'm using Devise gem.

here's the update method in article controller

```
def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    updated = @article.update(article_params) do |article|
      article.editor_id = current_user.id
    end

    if updated
      format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }.s: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

update process is success but it didn't save the user id. And plus, how to save the user id only if the article content changed? Any advice?

Comment: https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail is a good gem to keep track of changes to activerecord

Answer (score 1):

with direction from @sujan i change my code to this. i'm removing the update variable to make it more simpler

```
   def update

        @article.assign_attributes(article_params)   

        if  @article.content_changed?
           @article.editor_id = current_user.id    
        end

        respond_to do |format|
          if @article.save
            format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: "Article succesfully updated" }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the article after assigning the editor_id. Try,

```
updated = @article.update(article_params) do |article|
  article.editor_id = current_user.id
  article.save
end
```

or better,

```
updated = false
@article.assign_attributes(article_params)
if @article.changed?
  @article.editor_id = current_user.id
  updated = @article.save
end
```

This will update the article only if there are changes.

Refs:

1. [assign_attributes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes)
2. [changed](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty/changed%3F)

Comment: i'm using your second code suggestion, but if the article were not changed, and user press submit, it redirect back to the form. but i get the idea and i think i know how to fix it

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer if it answered your question

Comment: @Aipack You can also merge editor_id to the article_params:
`@article.assign_attributes(article_params.merge(editor_id: current_user.id))`
and then assign result to the variable `updated = @article.content_changed? ? @article.save : false`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out act as versioned: https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_versioned

The other way is that you create another model for it, which will logs the changes, and who did them. Like ArticleLog (article_id, user_id, changed_attr, prev_val).

Write a hook to create ArticleLog on update of Article, if the attribute you want to log is changed.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#updating-an-object

I hope I helped you! :)